# How to filter mongoose changeStream

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a chat system, and I try to use the changeStream of mongoDB / mongoose.

I only want to get document if the current user is the recipient, but It not works. So far I have met two cases. One never trigger and the other returned with all documents even if not the current user is the recipient.

The difference is the pipeline in an array or not.

Do you have any idea what is the right syntax?

---

I read all article that I found in google at the first 10 page in the last 2 days, but none of it contain how to filter. As I understand the aggregation pipe is only for manipulate the result, but its not possible to exclude documents that not pass the conditions.

---

here is what I have done:

```
const pipeline = [{
     $match: { 
         "userId": this.recipient.id,
         "recipientId": this.user.id
    }
}]

const stream = MessageModel.watch(pipeline )

stream.on('change', (data: any) => {
    console.log(`messages changed`);
    this.socketIo.sockets.in(this.socket.id).emit(`protected/message/subscribe/${this.msg.msgId}`, data.fullDocument);
});
```

Comment: I think this article will be very helpful for you https://thecodebarbarian.com/a-nodejs-perspective-on-mongodb-36-change-streams.html

Comment: I read all article (included this article) that i found in google at the first 10 page in the last 2 days, but none of it contain how to filter. As I understand the aggregation pipe is only for manipulate the result, but its not possible to exclude documents that not pass the conditions.

Comment: please share answer here if you found it, I think it will be actual for me in the coming days

Answer (score 0):

this might be useful

```
const { ReplSet } = require('mongodb-topology-manager');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

run().catch(error => console.error(error));

async function run() {
  console.log(new Date(), 'start');
  const bind_ip = 'localhost';
  // Starts a 3-node replica set on ports 31000, 31001, 31002, replica set
  // name is "rs0".
  const replSet = new ReplSet('mongod', [
    { options: { port: 31000, dbpath: `${__dirname}/data/db/31000`, bind_ip } },
    { options: { port: 31001, dbpath: `${__dirname}/data/db/31001`, bind_ip } },
    { options: { port: 31002, dbpath: `${__dirname}/data/db/31002`, bind_ip } }
  ], { replSet: 'rs0' });

  // Initialize the replica set
  await replSet.purge();
  await replSet.start();
  console.log(new Date(), 'Replica set started...');

  // Connect to the replica set
  const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:31000,localhost:31001,localhost:31002/' +
    'test?replicaSet=rs0';
  await mongoose.connect(uri);

  // To work around "MongoError: cannot open $changeStream for non-existent
  // database: test" for this example
  await mongoose.connection.createCollection('people');

  const Person = mongoose.model('Person', new mongoose.Schema({ name: String }));

  // Create a change stream. The 'change' event gets emitted when there's a
  // change in the database
  Person.watch().
    on('change', data => console.log(new Date(), data));

  // Insert a doc, will trigger the change stream handler above
  console.log(new Date(), 'Inserting doc');
  await Person.create({ name: 'Axl Rose' });
  console.log(new Date(), 'Inserted doc');
}
```

Comment: I use replica sets. In this code snippet the watch method is empty, but I think its parameter(s) is / are the key, if there are any key here.